# iTunes not syncing videos from the Photos app in Mac to iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos

I organize all of my photos and videos on the Photos app in Mac, (with everything in the folder Photos Library.photoslibrary). I also disabled all iCloud Photo Library , My Photo Stream and iCloud Photo Sharing.

Then I sync photos and videos through iTunes with the options "copy photos from Photos" . iTunes can correctly count the number of items in my Mac's Photos app (number of photos + number of videos). However, when it tries to sync the videos, itunes displays "syncing 140 videos" and then just skip over all of them. All the photos are synced correctly though.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Even tried a full restore, but no luck. Tried removing all photos and re-syncing, but also no success. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Having the same issue as well. Trying to find a solution. Will update you guys if I find one.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I found a way. It's a work around, but it works.

1. Email the video to yourself (email should be accessible on your iphone).
2. Save the video to your iCloud Drive
3. Save the video to your device (it will go to your camera roll).

Hope this helps others facing a similar issue.